# Make a Nest.JS project executable but without the source code exposed

Tags: node.js, binary, nestjs, executable, packing

If we want to deploy our NEST.js sever on the customer's environment, how can we hide our source code preventing from the plagiarism?

Comment: that applies to nodejs apps. Search on that instead of constraint it to nestjs. https://github.com/bytenode/bytenode might help you

Comment: I think `pkg` is a good package for these purposes: https://www.npmjs.com/package/pkg. As @MicaelLevi said, it applies to Nodejs apps. You can pass Nest.js compiled version (main.js) to `pkg.`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is impossible to completely hide your package implementation. What you can (and should) do is using Webpack to create a bundle and minify your exported code. With that, it is pretty hard for someone to reverse engineer your code, but it is still doable.

Since Javascript is not compiled to binary, the executable of your code will always be Javascript, therefore it could be reverse engineered.